# Deserializing .json and .xml files and verifying their structure

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization, deserialization

So quite recently I've faced a problem: I don't know how to verify correct structure of .xml and .json files. These files contain serialized List which contains objects from class BaseClass and it's derived classes. And what I am trying to achieve is verification of imported file, because it's impossible to import a file that doesn't match objects from BaseClass in List. Currently I'm using  XmlSerializer.Deserialize and Newtonsoft.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject methods in order to deserialize file, but this doesn't protect me from incorrect file structure (files are used to store tables, so they have same column names but different data).

Comment: XML has XSD schemas and JSON has JSON schemas that can be used to validate a file's contents

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've seen those examples but they're not clear to me at all, the thing that confused me was string that contain schema, because that string had some data in it and i don't quite understand how it works and how to get such schema string for my purposes.

Comment: My question is "Why aren't the people who are generating the XML doing the schema checking"?  I think it is wrong to distribute files that contain errors.  The people who are reading the files shouldn't be getting the errors in the first place.

Comment: @jdweng This is University home task, it's like a practice to teach us c# basics. So i should do this file check even if i know that it's useless in real life ;(